# Detecting hand movement with kinect?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

How can i detect that I am moving my hand, and that I stop moving it.
I want to to that, becuase I want to save the data of my left hand, just when i move to do gesture recognition

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Sample Project ‘BodyBasics-WPF’ – it sets up a BodyFrameReader, and then can look at the bodies detected and grab the joint.Key where JointType = JointType.HandLeft.  From there you can track the position (joint.Position – tracks in X/Y/Z) and see if it moves or is stationary.